Toastify toast.error not working in async function during login attempt
I'm using React with Redux and Toastify to display notifications in my app. When the user attempts to log in, I want to show a success toast if the login is successful, and an error toast if it fails. While the success toast works fine, the error toast does not appear when the login fails. Here's the code:
const handleLogin = async () => {
  if (!validateForm()) return;

  setIsSubmitting(true);
  setErrors({});

  try {
    await dispatch(login(email, password));
    toast.success('Logged in successfully!');
    navigate('/dashboard');
  } catch (err) {
    toast.error('Invalid email or password. Please try again.');
    setErrors({ api: err.message || 'Login failed. Please try again.' });
  } finally {
    setIsSubmitting(false);
  }
};

The success toast (toast.success) works as expected, but the error toast (toast.error) does not show up when there is a login failure. The error is being caught in the catch block, and the setErrors state is updated, but for some reason, the error toast does not appear.
Things I’ve tried so far:
I’ve confirmed that the catch block is being triggered (e.g., by logging the error message).
I’ve tried replacing toast.error with console.log to check if the function is even being called.
I’ve confirmed that other toasts (like success) not working .
Any suggestions on why the error toast isn't showing?

where do you put ToastContainer at?

In my div container, look my toast.sucess work but toast.error didn't.

Could you make a example in codesandbox or stackblitz?
